# CasperJS export to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, casperjs

I'm trying to export data with CasperJS to excel. I can't believe that have no way to do it.

```
var casper = require('casper').create(),
    fs = require('fs'),
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("file.xls");

casper.start('http://google.com');
casper.run();
```

any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Sure you can, but remember that it is easier to write a CSV file than a valid XLS file. Do you have any specific question? What kind of answers are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. CSV also no problem. Could you show me working example? Because my code above is not working

Comment: CasperJS is not a node.js module, but runs in PhantomJS which has a different execution environment. You will need to use its [`fs` module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/).

Comment: Great! Yes, issue was that I tried to use `fs` like `node.js` but should use it like `PhantomJS` module

Answer (score 0):

Main problem there is that `casperjs` for `fs` using `PhantomJS` module. So we can't use `fs.createWriteStream("file.xls")`. And better to use `csv` file for export instead `xls`. Than if we need we can convert it to Excel file.

*right code should look like this:*

```
var casper = require('casper').create(),
    fs = require('fs');

casper.start('http://google.com', function() {
    var path = 'output.csv';
    var content = 'Hello World!';
    fs.write(path, content, 'w');
});
casper.run();
```

Full documentation about **PhantomJS fs module** is [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/).

Answer (score 0):

see a working sample:

```
var fs = require('fs');
lines.forEach(function writeCSV(line) {
    stream = fs.open('file.csv','aw');
    stream.writeLine(line);
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
}
```

Extracted from an [old meetup sample](https://gist.github.com/mickaelandrieu/7657811).

Regards,